# Как вывести приветственное сообщение, когда пользователь вступает в чат или группу, Aiogram BOT?

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

Хочу выводить приветственное сообщение когда пользователь вступает в чат, группу, но не знаю как это сделать. Бот на Aiogram, Python. Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Нужно чтобы ботом выводился текст когда пользователь вступал в группу или чат. Как это сделать в Aiogram?

Answer (score 4):

Очень просто, для этого Вам нужен обработчик на новых участников группы:

```py
from aiogram.types import ContentType, Message

...

@dp.message_handler(content_types=[ContentType.NEW_CHAT_MEMBERS])
async def new_members_handler(message: Message):
    new_member = message.new_chat_members[0]
    await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Добро пожаловать, {new_member.mention}")
```